# WooCommerce: E-Mail Header Image not showing (blocked by E-Mail Client?)

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

The logo "St. Michael" is not showing up on my local E-Mail client (Apple Mail) nor on a web-based E-Mail client (Google Mail).

With the WooCommerce preview: [it works fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etetzact2nop6q7/Screenshot%202018-09-04%2016.07.46.png?dl=0)
In other E-Mail clients: [it doesn't show up](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buka7hgqem8apht/Screenshot%202018-09-04%2016.02.09.png?dl=0).

The image is on this path, behind htaccess:

http://shop.stmichael.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/logo_kellerei_footer.png

Comment: Have you tried to call the image via HTTPS?

Comment: There isn't yet a SSL certificate on the domain, maybe this could be the fix! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image was blocked because of the .htaccess file on the server.

Comment: You can mark your own message as the answer if your issue is solved. Thanks.

Comment: What did you add to your .htaccess file for it to display?

Comment: @Cyfer just removed my .htaccess file that was blocking the request.

Comment: @LukasHillebrand I see, that might not work for those who may need the .htaccess file. In such cases they might need to see what rule is blocking said request.